Livewire 3 not displaying the exact error
I installed a fresh livewire3 and added maryui to it. Why is it that when there is an error in the blade file, it always shows the same error message which is not very helpful in debugging? Here is the error that appears in the browser but when I open a laravel.log file, the exact error is shown there which is the more helpful error message.

And here is the exact error from the laravel.log which is more useful.
[2024-07-09 06:07:03] local.ERROR: Unable to locate a class or view for component [card]. {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to locate a class or view for component [card]. at D:\\livewire11\\maryui2\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Compilers\\ComponentTagCompiler.php:311)
[stacktrace]

